# Android BottomSheet with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I added a BottomSheet with a RecyclerView in it to my app, but I can't scroll the RecyclerView, and I can't find out what is the problem.

Here is my BottomSheet:

```
   <!-- bottom sheet -->
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
   style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   app:behavior_hideable="true"
   app:behavior_peekHeight="90dp"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <!-- horizontal thumbnail -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/horizontal_thumbnail"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="90dp"/>

    <!-- vertical thumbnail -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/vertical_thumbnail"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The vertical thumbnail is visible when the sheet is expanded, the horizontal is visible when the list is collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The problem was I added two RecyclerViews to the BottomSheet, and the second one didn't scroll in this case. I don't really need the first when and when I removed it, I was able to scroll the other.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can put the RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView.

Comment: really bad solution, because recyclerView will create and bind all its items, not only visible